# How to Zoom the Google Map from given 2 latitude and longtitude bound in flutter or dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, zooming

is working correct now, but anyone help for correction.

The below method is used for zoom factor.
I have doubt please check it.

[Output View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AafTu.jpg)

Comment: Please share code and package name for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Now the function is working correctly—even though I have doubts in it. Please let me know if you see any issues with this.

```
zoom(LatLngBounds value,padding){
    var maxY = value.southwest.longitude,minY = value.northeast.longitude,deltaX = value.southwest.latitude,centerX=0.0;
    var ry1 = math.log((math.sin(toRadian(minY))+1)/math.cos(toRadian(minY))) ;
    var ry2 = math.log((math.sin(toRadian(maxY))+1)/math.cos(toRadian(maxY))) ;
    var ryc = (ry1+ry2)/2.0;
    var centerY = toDegree(math.atan(Trath.sinh(ryc)));
    var resolutionHorizontal = deltaX/Get.width;
    var vy0 = math.log(math.tan(math.pi*(0.25+centerY/360.0)));
    var vy1 = math.log(math.tan(math.pi*(0.25+maxY/360.0)));
    var viewHeightHalf = Get.width/2.0;
    var zoomFactorPowered = viewHeightHalf/ (40.7436654315252*(vy1 - vy0));
    var resolutionVertical = 360.0/(zoomFactorPowered*256);
    var resolution = math.max(resolutionVertical, resolutionHorizontal)*padding;
    var zoom = math.log(360/(resolution*256))/math.log(2);
    print("!====E${zoom}");
    var lon =  centerX;
    var lat = centerY;
    return zoom;
}
```

Widget

```
GoogleMap(
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {

        if(bounds!=null){

         var dist =  Geolocator.distanceBetween(bounds!.northeast.latitude, bounds!.northeast.latitude, bounds!.southwest.latitude, bounds!.southwest.latitude);

         String round = "${dist.round()}";

         var nzf;
          if(round.length==5){
            nzf = 40;
          }else if(round.length==4){
            nzf = 52;
          }else if(round.length==3){
            nzf = 85;
          }else if(round.length==2){
            nzf = 95;
          }

          var zf = nzf/(zoom(bounds!,600)*-1);
          print("=Zoom Factor==${round} ${dist} == ${zf}");

          //_controller.complete()

          controller?.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
               CameraPosition(

                target:center!,

                zoom: zf,
              ),
            ),
          );

          // controller.animateCamera(u2).then((void v){
          //   check(u2,controller);
          // });

        }

      },
    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,

    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: center!,zoom: 14
    ),
    mapType: MapType.satellite,
    tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
    buildingsEnabled: true,
    indoorViewEnabled: true,
    mapToolbarEnabled: true,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
    rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
    myLocationEnabled: true,
    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
    //trafficEnabled: true,
    zoomControlsEnabled: true,
    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
    compassEnabled: true,

    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values), //polylines

  )
```

Comment: @Shaido: I misflagged this post, as the explanation that this was, in fact, intended as a solution was buried in the bottom of the code block, and not displayed as normal text. I've edited the answer to correct for that. That said, the _question_ should probably be closed since it doesn't provide enough information for other people to answer this or even make sense of this answer.